# work with same dll but with different version

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint, dll

In my SharePoint application in use the 3 version of Microsoft.SharePoint.dll (version 12,for SharePoint2007, version14 for Sharepoint2010, and version 15 for SharePoint2013 ),
The problem is all those three dll have the same name space.
I even chage the assembly name (to added to the references ) but the name space stil the same.

any idea.

Comment: If you just compile against version 14, it will use that running under 2010 and the version 15 one under 2013. It's probably the same if you compile against version 12, but trying to have one solution that runs under both SP2007 and SP2013 sounds like more effort than it's worth...

Comment: There is no problem that all dll's have the same namespace. There would be problems if namespaces would be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you, I just found the solution here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx , and It works 
Short story:

First of all, we must rename the assembly to have the possibility to added it to the project
•"just right click the assembly -> Rename"

Second: 
•Go to the properties of the assembly and change the alias to other alias like "SP2010" just at the first line in the class add "extern alias SP2010;"

Third: 
•use SP2010::Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication instead of SPWebApplication etc